# Issues with LogShipping in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Tags: sql-server, database, server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I've got two SQL instances in two separate servers, 
The first one has two databases, A and B for that purpose, that I'm logshipping to the secondary server; in database A it works like a charm, however, when logshipping database B we encounter errors, the database enters suspect mode, haven't been able to figure out why.

The secondary server used to be the main one, and it had logshipping to a third server, which stopped working. When the secondary server was our main one we never encountered logshipping issues, both databases A and B were logshipping without issues for a long period of time.

We installed the same SQL Server version on the new server as we had on the previous one and reconfigured the SQL Agent Jobs to get it up and running, database A has encountered no errors so far, however we can't seem to get the second database running for longer than a few hours.

All research I've done has led no-where, there's a few things that I've seen suggested online and we've ran our tests with no success so far.

To point out: Database A is much larger than B, however this one has had no issues whatsoever.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 3.

Any help to anyone who might have encountered this in the past would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do the logs say? windows logs, SQL Server logs, SQL Agent logs

Comment: Logs only suggest the transaction (.trn) is faulty. That's what we've been able to conclude, but we don't know the reason for it.